# Trying to summarize_at, but return a corresponding column (rather than the column that is used to select the correct row)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to select the BMI with the lowest difference between the BMI and the BMI mode for a person on a given day. So I want to group by 2 things: ID (called MRN) and OBSERVATION_DATE. I have created a variable that is the absolute value of the difference between the BMI3 and the BMI mode. And I want to select the row for each person/day that has the lowest absolute value difference. However, I don't want to return the absolute value difference, I want to return the BMI3.

Here is a sample of the data

```
BMIdf<-structure(list(MRN = c(8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 
                         9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 
                         9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 
                         9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 
                         9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 
                         9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 76133L, 
                         76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 
                         76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 
                         76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 
                         76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L
), OBSERVATION_DATE = structure(c(18039, 18058, 18086, 18102, 
                              18128, 18494, 15747, 15817, 15845, 18134, 18152, 
18153, 18169, 
                              18183, 18183, 18184, 18205, 18205, 18205, 18214, 
18226, 18226, 
                              18234, 18235, 18242, 18247, 18249, 18249, 18267, 
18288, 18288, 
                              18310, 18330, 18351, 18373, 18393, 18414, 18435, 
18457, 18478, 
                              18499, 18520, 18541, 18541, 18716, 18716, 16762, 
16779, 16780, 
                              16790, 16790, 16791, 16807, 16807, 16821, 16835, 
16868, 16869, 
                              16874, 16877, 16881, 16919, 16975, 17017, 17077, 
17280, 17290, 
                              17318, 17318, 17326, 17326, 17331, 17331, 17333, 
17336, 17339, 
                              17347, 17360, 17381, 17402, 17423, 17444, 17465), 
tzone = "America/Denver", class = "Date"), 
BMI3 = c(37.79, 37.59, 38.45, NA, 37.95, NA, NA, 29.7140831758034, 
     NA, 29.45, 28.67, 28.67, 29.8, 29.98, NA, 30.28, NA, 29.63, 
     29.45, 28.77, 29.03, 28.45, 28.91, 29.01, 28.54, 28.88, 28.2032837245696, 
     28.2, 28.79, 28.2, 28.2, 28.49, 28.94, 28.13, 28.55, 28.14, 
     27.77, 28.15, 27.7, 27.86, 27.88, 28.1, 28.31, 28.3, NA, 
     NA, 34.52, NA, 35.28, 34.92, 34.75, NA, 34.16, 35.15, 34.06, 
     34.53, 34.26, 33.73, 33.47, NA, 32.54, 32.39, 33.05, 33.4, 
     33.51, 32.93, 30.42, NA, 32.14, 32.12, 32.12, 32.35, 33.01, 
     33.08, NA, 32.73, 32.65, 31.71, 31.48, 31.23, 31.48, 31.83, 
     31.12), BMI3_mode_diff_abs = c(0.210000000000001, 0.409999999999997, 
                                    0.450000000000003, NA, 0.0499999999999972, NA, 
NA, 1.7140831758034, 
                                    NA, 1.45, 0.670000000000002, 
0.670000000000002, 1.8, 1.98, 
                                    NA, 2.28, NA, 1.63, 1.45, 0.77, 1.03, 
0.449999999999999, 
                                    0.91, 1.01, 0.539999999999999, 
0.879999999999999, 0.20328372456963, 
                                    0.199999999999999, 0.789999999999999, 
0.199999999999999, 
                                    0.199999999999999, 0.489999999999998, 
0.940000000000001, 
                                    0.129999999999999, 0.550000000000001, 
0.140000000000001, 
                                    0.23, 0.149999999999999, 0.300000000000001, 
0.140000000000001, 
                                    0.120000000000001, 0.100000000000001, 
0.309999999999999, 
                                    0.300000000000001, NA, NA, 1.52, NA, 2.28, 
1.92, 1.75, NA, 
                                    1.16, 2.15, 1.06, 1.53, 1.26, 
0.729999999999997, 0.469999999999999, 
                                    NA, 0.460000000000001, 0.609999999999999, 
0.0499999999999972, 
                                    0.399999999999999, 0.509999999999998, 
0.0700000000000003, 
                                    2.58, NA, 0.859999999999999, 
0.880000000000003, 0.880000000000003, 
                                    0.649999999999999, 0.00999999999999801, 
0.0799999999999983, 
                                    NA, 0.270000000000003, 0.350000000000001, 
1.29, 1.52, 1.77, 
                                    1.52, 1.17, 1.88)), row.names = c(NA, -83L), 
class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                           
"data.frame"))
```

I don't want to use summarise, as it is an old function. I am trying to use summarise_at. But this just returns the absolute value difference, when I want to return the BMI3 that is on the same row as that absolute value difference

```
BMI_same_day<-BMIdf %>% 
  group_by(MRN, OBSERVATION_DATE) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(BMI3_mode_diff_abs),list(BMI_same_day=min))
```

The expected output is BMI3. I am trying to write it so that it goes and finds the lowest absolute value difference (BMI3_mode_diff_abs) for a given person and OBSERVATION_DATE. Hence I use "min". But then I don't want it to return the BMI3_mode_diff_abs that is the lowest. I want it to return the BMI3 that is on the same row as the lowest BMI3_mode_diff_abs.

Comment: Given your test data, what is your expected output?  It is not clear to me.  Do you perhaps need a variant of `slice` rather than `summaruse` or `filter`?  Also, not that `summarise_at` has been superseded by `summarise(across())` in recent versions of `dplyr`.

Comment: The expected output is BMI3. I am trying to write it so that it goes and finds the lowest absolute value difference (BMI3_mode_diff_abs) for a given person and OBSERVATION_DATE. Hence I use "min". But then I don't want it to return the BMI3_mode_diff_abs that is the lowest. I want it to return the BMI3 that is on the same row as the lowest BMI3_mode_diff_abs.

Comment: Then you need `… slice_min(BMI3_mode_diff_abs) %>% pull(BMI3)`.